# LG VS980 Bricked

Tags: lg

I got a LG VS980, don't know what version exactly I only managed to get to the home screen for a short while. Everytime I start the phone it's stuck on the LG screen, I boot into factory reset (it doesn't work and shows a dead android) and open system recovery and get this:

```
[Recovery.cpp][main()] ############### factory reset sart ##################, Thu Jan 1 00:22:18 1970

E:failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
[recovery.cpp] system partition mount failed!!
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
```

Continues with many more lines of can't open and mount.
The recovery thing gives me a few options:

```
reboot system now <-- Just boots into the infinite LG screen
apply update from ABD
wipe data/factory reset <-- Tried this, doesn't work
wipe cache partition <-- Also doesn't work
reboot to bootloader <-- Just boots into the infinite LG screen
power down
view recovery logs
apply update from sdcard <-- This phone doesn't have an SD card slot (atleast I couldn't find it)
```

I think booting from ABD would work only problem is I can't access my phones internal storage...

Just so it's clear: I got this phone about a week ago from Verizon, I got this error not even a day after getting the phone. I go back to the store the next day and they are unwilling to replace it or help me (apparently what I did, which was nothing, voided warranty). This is my last hope to save this crap before I buy a new one from else where.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I've gotten ADB to work to an extent. I got the OTA file and the program ready to go, now ADB can't find the phone to send it the files. I have the Android SDK which I got from the android studio, it still will not find it. I know you usually have to set it to debugging mode and what not, but remember I can't access the phone's home screen. I'm still digging, so I'll update if I make any progress.

Second edit: I'm thinking this thing is toast, I've gotten the computer to recognize the phone but now the phone is saying this:

```
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:failed to mount /cache
E:failed to set up expected mounts for install; aborting
Installation aborted.
```

Third edit: I don't know why this happens, but if I leave the phone off for a bit, it will boot to the main screen. I am able to access the things I would need to flash the damn thing.

Comment: After messing around a bit and digging a bit more into ADB, the phone can connect to the computer but it's unable to access the files. I'm going to keep digging see if I can't figure this out.

Comment: I remember messing with these years ago when they first came out, like 2013 or so... They were good phones in their time but finicky as heck even back then, especially the internal eMMC (the internal storage chip), we saw a lot of them go bad and fail back when they were still pretty new. They shipped with KitKat, but later the Lollipop update came out and made them extremely difficult to modify or flash, and it seems to me caused a lot of bricking as well. Not to be a downer, but it is very likely toast. Even people who got them JTAG programmed saw them fail shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try flashing a new OS. I have personally never done it before. But, I strongly recommend sticking with the same OS version, as there will most probably be compatability issues